# Why iterator type is mismatched with value_type * in vector container?

Tags: c++, vector, stl

According to the latest STL source code, I can find the following in stl_vector.h

```
template <class _Tp, class _Alloc = __STL_DEFAULT_ALLOCATOR(_Tp) >
class vector : protected _Vector_base<_Tp, _Alloc>   
{
private:
  typedef _Vector_base<_Tp, _Alloc> _Base;
public:
  typedef _Tp value_type;
  typedef value_type* pointer;
  typedef const value_type* const_pointer;
  typedef value_type* iterator;
  typedef const value_type* const_iterator;
  typedef value_type& reference;
  typedef const value_type& const_reference;
  typedef size_t size_type;
  typedef ptrdiff_t difference_type;
...

int main() {
vector<string>::iterator it;

cout << "iterator type check 1 " << (typeid(it) == typeid(string *)) << endl;
cout << "iterator type check 2" << (typeid(vector<string>::iterator) == typeid(vector<string>::value_type *)) << endl;
cout << "iterator type check 3" << (typeid(vector<string>::pointer) == typeid(vector<string>::value_type *)) << endl;
cout << "iterator type check 4" << (typeid(string *) == typeid(vector<string>::value_type *)) << endl;
```

}

however, when I use clang++ compile the main above, I got the mismatch result for iterator and value_type *. 
result is 1/2 not match, 3/4 are matched. However, I expected 1/2 should be matched as well.
Is this because I am referring the latest stl code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The STL is not the C++ standard library. The C++ standard allows an implementation to use a pointer for random access iterators, but does not dictate it. Both clang and gcc use user-defined types for these iterators, rather than pointers. Neither is GCC.

You need to look at the implementation of the code you are actually trying to compile. And that is not the STL.

For example, on gcc 4.8 `std::vector::iterator` is

```
typedef __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<pointer, vector> iterator;
```

where `__normal_iterator` is a class template.

Comment: Cool, thanks! I was not aware of this before your answer, the naming is confusing. Your answer definitely explains my test result. I have downloaded gcc source and it is using a different type. I am very new to stackoverflow so sorry I can't vote for you.